# Capistrano + Digital Ocean + Rails: An unhandled lowlevel error occurred. The application logs may have details

Tags: ruby-on-rails, digital-ocean, capistrano3

I have deployed Ruby on Rails 5 application on Digital Ocean(DO) Ubuntu's 16.04 server. When I try to access application from browser i got the following error: `An unhandled lowlevel error occurred. The application logs may have details.` I have searched it on Google everybody is saying it is because of `missing_secret_key`. I have done following things.
- create and store the rake secret in environment variable
- setting environment variable in `/etc/profile`
- setting environment variable  `/etc/environments`

I don't know why still I am getting this error. I have checked the viroment variable by printing its value:

```
$ echo $SECRET_KEY_BASE
$ 1463fa11e7063d0b1b6d82e62a9ed0c412d101f61a6812f0b3ed26cccf3b7259ac6f854997357a7ae84e0e91ec386e91029f878bfc175c39df7011189b487ba
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: _The application logs may have details_ - what does log show?

Comment: I can't find the application logs. actually i am new to ubuntu and digital ocean. can you please tell me where can i find the logs? @PavelMikhailyuk

Comment: You have to investigate your Capistrano config for app path. Than search for something like `/app_path/current/log/env_name.log`

Comment: Thanks @PavelMikhailyuk, I tried to look at /app_path/current/log/env_name.log. but unfortunately I could not fine the current directory inside the application directory.   It gives no directory error `cd: /home/talha/apps/GeekyCricket/current/log`

Comment: It is very strange: when you are using Capistrano, you have the structure http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/structure/

Comment: I have followed the following tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma

Comment: Is `talha` your deploy user?

Comment: Nope, its user on My mac. I am using this configuration  `set :deploy_to,       "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"`.

Comment: You have to read how Capistrano works. `fetch(:user)` is not your local user, but deploy one(which is `deploy` by default). So, you have to check path like `/home/deploy/apps/GeekyCricket/current/log` and not one you checked before. Also, you can get all info from console output while Capistrano deploy is running.

Comment: Thank you so much @PavelMikhailyuk.

Comment: I found out the production.log file. Why it is still showing Missing `secret_key_base`, while echo $SECRET_KEY_BASE shows the assigned value.

Comment: Did you run `echo $SECRET_KEY_BASE` under `deploy` user?

Comment: Yeah. It print out the string: `1463fa11e7063d0b1b6d82e62a9ed0c412d101f61a6812f0b3ed26cccf3b7259ac6f854997357a7ae84e0e91ec386e91029f878bfc175c39df7011189b487ba2`

Comment: Do you run your app with `Upstart` ?

Comment: Nope I didn't how can I do that?

Comment: 1) Do you ever read `secret_key_base` from `ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]` in `secrets.yml` for _production_ environment? 2) How do you run your rails app ?

Comment: 1. yes I am reading it using ENV `production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>` .   2. when I execute `Cap Production Deploy` it restarts the nginx server

Comment: 2. Nginx is a front web-server. And you have something like Puma to run your Rails app. The main question is How do you run Puma? 3. Could you run `RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails c` from console under `deploy` user?

Comment: Starting puma like this `task :initial do
    on roles(:app) do
      before 'deploy:restart', 'puma:start'
      invoke 'deploy'
    end
  end` .    3. Yes, Environment production loads successfully

Comment: Try to add `export SECRET_KEY_BASE=...` to `/home/deploy/.bashrc`